# NHibernateUtil.Date.SqlType uses DateTime

Tags: nhibernate

I have a sql server 2008 database with a column with the type Date. I get performance problems with nhibernate since nhibernate writes the sql as type DateTime and sql string like `'2012-05-01 00:00:00'`, this results in a bad query plan.

It works if the type is correct like Date and sql string '2012-05-01' i.e. .ToShortDateString.

So even if I tell nhibernate I want `NHibernate.Type.DateType`, the sql output is incorrect, it will use DateTime and `'2012-05-01 00:00:00'`.

I've tried to debug the`NHibernate`code but it's hard since I couldn't make vs.net stop optimizing so I can't watch locals.

Any clues?

Comment: looking at the code NHibernate just sets a Parameter on the command to the datetime hence it must be the ADO.NET provider which has this behaviour. Try using sqlcommand with a date parameter directly to see if this is true. if it is you have to implement DateTime conversion yourself